# Scrolling and clicklistener on views

Tags: java, android, scroll, onclicklistener

I have an `Adapter` that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Each line of adapter is a custom FrameLayout with GestureDetector implemented. The `FrameLayout xml` file has 2 `RelativeLayout`.
In this `FrameLayout` I redirect X and Y positions to the `RelativeLayout` that is in the foreground.

In each `RelativeLayout` I have a `setOnClickListener`. This is because if user clicks the `RelativeLayout` that is on the foreground, an `activity` is started. If the user scrolls the former, the latter is available to click.

What I'm facing is:
Implementing `setOnClickListener` on these layouts I lost view scroll feature of my custom `FrameLayout`. And I need the scroll feature and `clickListener` for each view.

**This is my xml**

```
 file:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/work_order_deleted_item_background_color">

    ...
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**My custom FrameLayout:**

```
public class SwipeView extends FrameLayout implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{
    private RelativeLayout container;
    private RelativeLayout backgroundContainer;
    private GestureDetector detector;
    private float posX;
    private float posY;
    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private float xLimit;

    private int mActivePointerId;

    public SwipeView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_work_order, this);
        initViews(context, null);

        xLimit = 200.0f;
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        detector = new GestureDetector(this);
    }

    public SwipeView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initViews(context, attrs);

        xLimit = 200.0f;
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        detector = new GestureDetector(this);
    }

    public SwipeView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initViews(context, attrs);

        xLimit = 200.0f;
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        detector = new GestureDetector(this);
    }

    private void initViews(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        this.container = this.findViewById(R.id.container);
        this.backgroundContainer = this.findViewById(R.id.background_container);
        this.checkboxDownload = this.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_download);
        this.textviewWo = this.findViewById(R.id.textview_wo);
        this.downloadedWo = this.findViewById(R.id.textview_downloaded_wo);
        this.textviewTime = this.findViewById(R.id.textview_time);
        this.textviewField1 = this.findViewById(R.id.textview_field_1);
        this.textviewField2 = this.findViewById(R.id.textview_field_2);
        this.textviewField3 = this.findViewById(R.id.textview_field_3);
        this.deleteLabel = this.backgroundContainer.findViewById(R.id.delete_wo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
                final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, pointerIndex);
                final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, pointerIndex);

                // Remember where we started (for dragging)
                lastTouchX = x;
                lastTouchY = y;
                // Save the ID of this pointer (for dragging)
                mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, 0);

                if(x > container.getRight() + container.getX()){
                    Log.e("ERROR", "TOUCHED OUTSIDE");
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "TOUCHED INSIDE: ");
                }
                    break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(event, mActivePointerId);

                final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, pointerIndex);
                final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, pointerIndex);

                // Calculate the distance moved
                final float dx = x - lastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - lastTouchY;

                posX += dx;
                posY += dy;

                if(posX <= -xLimit){
                    posX -= dx;
                }

                if(posX > 0.0f){
                    posX = 0.0f;
                }

                invalidate();

                // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                lastTouchX = x;
                lastTouchY = y;

                container.setX(posX);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**And this code is inside my adapter:**

```
holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //onItemClickListener.onItemClick(workOrder);
                Log.e("ERROR", "FOREGROUND CLICKED");
            }
        });

        holder.backgroundContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Log.e("ERROR", "BACKGROUND CLICKED");
            }
        });
```

**Finally this is the code that is inside my Activity:**

```
((MyAdapter) recyclerview.getAdapter())
                .setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Item item) {
                if(!presenter.getDownloadAvailability()) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="false">
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/work_order_deleted_item_background_color">

    ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. Neither considers foreground view and clicks in each of them.

Comment: In adapter: adapter: implements  View.OnClickListener,
holder.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.holder ) {
}}